# As of 2019, are there alternatives to the official Skype client?

Tags: windows, skype, user-interface

I know that there is no full-scale alternative client as the Skype protocol is closed, but perhaps there is an alternative UI for the official Skype client?

Comment: You might have noticed that the question is closed as off-topic. It will remain that way, because software recommendations are off-topic. So you can stop editing the question every year, because nobody will be able to answer anyway.

Comment: @DanielB its not about software recommendations, its about whether or not any options are at all available

Comment: We have a sister site where questions like this are completely on-topic: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ Your attempt to show this is not a software rec doesn't really matter. According to the community rules here, this question is a request for software. It is also asking us to do a Google search for you. Both of these reasons will prevent this question from being re-opened here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Now there is a Web UI. This does not provide the whole features, but at least it is not a resource-hog.
https://web.skype.com/

Comment: Also the hotmail webpage has Skype chat column, and does hide ads :D. But, both Skype, Hotmail interface and web.skype sucks. Everyone has BIG bad things on it...

As i read on their own forum, Skype is the most well-made core with the worst designed UI ever made. Why do I need 3 bad UI? Make just one that works and do not close the core to make them better.

Answer (score 3):

As you have mentioned, Skype's protocol was never published, so no alternative clients are available.

There's a IM Client I know called [Miranda IM](http://miranda-ng.org/en/), which integrates to Skype but requires it to be running in the background.

If you're into gaming, you can try [Overwolf](http://www.overwolf.com/) or [Xfire](http://www.xfire.com/), which both integrate to Skype and other Social Media sites (ex. Facebook).